# Text is readable in Chrome; microscopic in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome, font-size

I have some text on a page that is small but readable in Chrome/Safari (that's how I intend it to be), but becomes microscopic in Firefox for some reason. Can anyone suggest a fix so that the text is readable in Firefox and IE?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>

<head>
    <title>WTF LBJ?!</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<style type="text/css">

#credit {font-family: "helvetica"; font-size: 20%; color: black; text-align:center; }

</style>

<body>

    <div id="credit"; >
        Created by <a href="http://www.twitter.com/varunsshetty">Varun Shetty</a> and <a href="http://www.twitter.com/bcfromblo">Bobby Corp</a>. Inspired by LBJ and <a href="http://www.whatthefuckhasobamadonesofar.com">WTF Obama</a>. Bobby loves Lebron; Varun loves the idea of Lebron.<br>
        Sorry for the swear word, but LBJ gets people fired up.
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "20%" means 20% of the default font size, which is pretty much unreadable on most screens. Perhaps you should go 70% or something like that.

Comment: It seems Chrome interprets the percentage differently... In any case, to avoid other problems, remove the ";" from the div tag.
p.s. Obama has done a lot more than you think, that site is too easy criticism.

Comment: thank you both. and i love obama - i think that WTF site is actually showing people all the good stuff he's done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`20%` is equal to `0.2em`, or 1/5 of the font size. My guess is that Chrome / Safari have a minimum font size configured to keep this readable. Try adjusting the `font-size` to something higher, like `0.4em` and see if it actually becomes bigger in Chrome / Safari.  If it doesn't, you've just hit a browser-defined minimum and the "real" font size is actually smaller.

↪ [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2YsH/1/)

Comment: Both Chrome and Firefox have a user setting for minimum font size. Howevere, authors should not rely on it being set (especially since it mostly isn’t). Setting font size to less 60% will cause serious trouble to many, if not most, users.

Comment: The minimum font size appears to be off by default in Firefox. You can turn it on via *Menu > Options > Fonts and colors > Advanced > Minimum font size*, by the way.

Comment: I just found that the user can't switch the minimum font size in Chrome off completely. You can set it to as low as 6px, but not lower. So Firefox gives the user more control over this setting.

Answer (score 1):

try and set font-size to a specific number instead of %, like 8pt or 10px

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if it is because you are using a low percentage on the particular font. By default, most browsers display fonts relative to 16px. So, when you defined `#credit {font-size: 20%;}`, you were telling the browser, *"I want 20% of 16px, or a size of around 3.2px."*  Here's a possible solution...

When I go about building websites, I always first set a default font size on my `body` tag. I have read several places on the web, (incl. Chris Coyier's popular CSS-tricks blog) that if you set `body {font-size: 62.5%;}`, this will actually help in making fonts similar in size between varying browsers.

Setting a font-size in pixels is ok if you're targeting screen devices (as it appears some have already suggested), although I'm starting to become a fan of *ems* as they seem pretty powerful.  *Ems* are good in the sense that they are always relative to the parent (in this example, your `body` text).  If you set font-sizes on your other page elements in *ems* based off of your `body` font-size, which is 62.5% (translated = ~16px), then you're golden.  You're providing your users with the most flexibility and you're also supporting IE browsers to zoom in and out without degrading the fonts...always helpful for users who might need to zoom in a bit to read something or zoom out a bit to see the whole page.

By using this method of *ems* and setting a default `body` font-size, everything in *ems* can be almost literally converted.  So, for example, if you want some text to be 10px in size, just set your font-size to 1.0em.  If you want a font-size of 22px, set your font-size to 2.2em...12px = 1.2em, 72px = 7.2em, etc.

In short, try setting your `body {font-size: 62.5%;}` and then setting `#credit {font-size: 0.8em;}`. This should give you a similar font-size between browser windows of 8px. Adjust accordingly if you would like something smaller or a little larger.

The even simpler answer would be to just use pixels like others have suggested, but like I said, create your sites with your users in mind. :)

Hope that helps!